# How can I set PulseAudio to use convolution

Tags: audio

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 and PulseAudio.

I made impulse to correct bass response on my speakers and would like to use it globally.

I can set Jack through jack-convolve plugin to use my impulse, but as not all applications can use Jack, nor do I run it all the time, I'm looking for a more robust solution.

It seems like I could use LADSPA plugins through module-ladspa-sink set in configuration file, but:

1. I don't know the syntax
2. Even if I knew syntax to set this module, it seems there are only pre-build impulses with LADSPA Impulse convolver, and I'm not sure if I could use my own.

Comment: What do you mean by impulse? Is this a program?

Answer (score 3):

You could run Jack all the time and route pulse output through it. Only minimal cpu and latency cost, but then no second convonluter, maintenance,etc needed.

```
$ sudo aptitde install pulseaudio-module-jack
```

and call

```
$ pactl load-module module-jack-sink
```

now pulse shall play everything to jack, and jack to the convolve pljugin, ant that to speaker. Use qjackctl and jack-meterbringe to debug any problems.